Why is changing a task dependency 'Type' via code throwing an exception?
Why is this code throwing an exception?
Public Sub TryChangeDependencyType(tDep As MSProject.TaskDependency)

    tDep.Type = pjStartToStart

End Sub



The Type property is read/write, so what gives? This only happens on one specific project (other projects don't throw an exception with that code) so there is something weird going on with that project but I don't know what I should be looking for.
I can change the dependency type in the Task Form pane, just not via code.
The project is a standard MS Project file (no inserted subprojects) and is saved on the C drive. I'm not using Project Server or Project Online.

If you haven’t already tried rebuilding that file, my guess is that file is corrupted. I don’t know if this is still the case, but for versions in the 1990-2003 range we had projects get corrupted on occasion and restoring the previous version, which seemed fine, often led to the same place—the file became corrupted again. In other words, the seeds of corruption were there even if the file looked and behaved okay.
